# firestore onDelete event triggers other delete events

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use the OnDelete trigger for my Cloud Functions on Firestore. I have two collections "alerts" and "logs". The Log object has an "alertId" key. What I'm trying to do is when an Alert is deleted to delete all the corespondent logs using a cloud function.

Something like that:

```
    exports.deleteLogs = functions.database.instance('my-app').ref('/alerts/{alertId}')
        .onDelete((snap) => {
            snap.ref('logs',ref => ref.where('alertId', '==', alertId)).delete();
    });
```

Comment: collections are in firestore not firebase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can trigger a function when a Firestore document is deleted like this:

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.firestore
    .document('alerts/{alertID}')
    .onDelete((snap, context) => {
      // Get an object representing the document prior to deletion
      const deletedValue = snap.data();

      // From there, get the deleted alert's id and delete all logs 
      // with that alertId key
    });
```