# Firestore cascade delete every item with same deleted ID

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am having problems when I delete an item.

[image: Subject list]

When I delete the subject I want to delete the task with the same id as subject

[image: Task list]

I tried with

```
mFirestore.collection("classes").document(classID).collection("subjects").document(subjectID).delete().addOnCompleteListener {
     mFirestore.collection("classes").document(classID).collection("tasks").whereEqualTo("subject", subjectID).get().addOnCompleteListener{ task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            for (document in task.result)
                mFirestore.collection("classes").document(classID).collection("tasks").document(document.id).delete()
        }
    }
}
```

but without success.

Now I want to do this action using firebase funcions. How can I do this?
Code in java or kotlin is the same

Comment: "I am having an issue when I delete an item". What issue do you have? Do you have an error?

Comment: no error, I just don't know how to do this

Comment: So you are calling `delete()` function, right? What is happening when you are using that line of code?

Comment: The only thing that immediately jumps out is that you hard-coded the document ID in the inner delete: `mFirestore.collection("classes").document("class1").collection("tasks").document(document.id).delete()`. That should probably be `mFirestore.collection("classes").document(classId).collection("tasks").document(document.id).delete()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
mFirestore.collection("classes").document(classID).collection("subjects").document(subjectID)
        .delete()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                mFirestore.collection("classes").document(classID).collection("tasks").whereEqualTo("subject", subjectID).get().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult())
                {
                mFirestore.collection("classes").document(classID).collection("tasks").document(documentSnapshot.getId()).delete();
                }
            }
        }
    });
     }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error deleting document", e);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'll try this evening. Thank you for answering

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Dude that's totally working as I was expecting! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion you can look for Cloud Functions. The responsibility of deleting subsequent documents in cascade should not be on the client's device. What if the user has a connection error in the middle of deleting the documents? With cloud functions you can do this exact same thing but on the server not on the client. Although this requires you to understand some basic JS.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_deleted

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49903118/13150066